# Problem with copying "/home/phablet/" from ubuntu phone to Linux PC

Tags: ubuntu-touch, backup, contacts, copy, sms

I am going on holiday, and am scared of loosing my Ubuntuphone which has all my contacts and SMS text messages.  I have read the article on here about backup which says to copy /home/phablet/ (on the phone) to somewhere else.

My problem however, is that when I connect my Ubuntuphone to my computer via USB it only gives me access to the pictures (and the micro SD card) etc.  The pictures copy fine, but I need to copy the phone's system files in /home/phablet/ (the whole directory to be safe), but I can not get access to /home/phablet/ on a remote device.  I tried copying to the SD card via a Terminal app on the phone, but that did not work.

I also tried a Bluetooth dongle, connection established with my PC but I can only seem to send files from my PC to my Ubuntuphone (not the other way around).

I just need a simple solution to enable me to copy /home/phablet/ from my Ubuntuphone to my Linux PC.  Please help.

Comment: Try using adb pull

Answer (score 1):

Do You know the adb tools?

Here are some instructions how it should work for you*:

1. Install adb tools on your Ubuntu desktop PC: `sudo apt-get install adb`
2. Enable developer mode at your Ubuntu Touch Device: System settings > about > deleoper mode
3. Connect your device via USB to your PC.
4. Use adb pull to pull files and folders:`adb pull /home/phablet/. ./backup`
   If you use adb tools the first time, you will need to confirm access at the device and start this command again.
5. Go and drink some coffee and have a great time until transfer is finished.
6. Go for your holidays.

*written with Ubuntu Touch, Nexus 4.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ssh server running on your linux PC you should be able to copy the whole /home/phablet directory using the scp command from a terminal on your phone. See http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp for more info on how to use scp.

Comment: Thankyou for this suggestion.  I have had a go at it, but it seems a little too complicated for me to master before I go on holiday.  I tried to self-study for CompTIA Linux+ but I am just not up to it.  Essentially I only need to backup up my Contacts and SMS Messages from my Ubuntu phone.  Is there any other simple way I can do this ?  I found the Wammu program in the Linux Mint Software Centre on my 64 bit home built Linux Box.  However I have no idea what settings I would need to use.